# Google ads crashes my application

Tags: android, layout, admob, manifest, ads

I want to add Google Ads (AdMob) in my application

Now I my app keeps crashing after adding it.

The logcat says:

> The meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not have the
>   right value.  Expected 6587000 but found 7571000.  You must have the
>   following declaration within the  element: < meta-data
>   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
>   android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

I've added everything in the manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
       <meta-data 
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Can someone help me fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your compile version of Google Play Services:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: I'm using eclipse, should I remove the old google play services and add the new one?

Comment: @Hadi I haven't used Eclipse for Android development before. What do you have there currently? Change your version number to 7.5.0 to use the newest version of Google Play Services.

Comment: You should be using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads`